# Find forgotten IP address of bridge

Tags: networking, router, nmap

About a year ago, I took my FIOS router and set it up as a bridge to allow me to connect my own router.  Worked great (made sure to clone the MAC address etc. etc.) then and is still working just fine.

So, it's wired `COAX->Bridge->Router` and all is well. BUT...

The bridge device has an IP address for configuration *but I can't remember what it is.*  I know it's not accessible unless I'm directly connected to it, so I've connected a laptop to the router's LAN ports.  I assigned myself a 192.168.1.37/24 address, because I thought I left the original router on that subnet, and tried hitting all the usual hosts (192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.254, etc.) and nothing.

Broke out `nmap` and scanned the entire class C... and nothing except my laptop responded.

Assigned myself a 192.168.0.10/16 address and `nmap`ped the entire /16, and nothing except the laptop responded.  But I'm 99% sure I wouldn't have picked (say) a 172.16.x.x or 10.x.x.x address.

Long story short: how do I find my bridge?  I would really like to avoid a factory reset of the bridge device, though that would be one way.  Anyone know any other tricks?

Comment: Can you do a broadcast/flood ping and then dump the arp table?

Comment: In my gateway, bridge interface is accessible even if i am not connected directly to the ethernet port or wireless. But it has a different ip block. Try 192.168.100.1 or myfiosgateway.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do some broadcast and all-hosts multicast pings:

```
ping 255.255.255.255
ping 224.0.0.1
```

…then look at your ARP table:

```
arp -an
```

Second, If that didn't work, hook up your machine directly to the bridge, start running `tcpdump`, then power-cycle the bridge. Boxes often ARP for their own IP address or transmit other IP traffic at boot. See if you see anything that's not from your own machine.

Comment: The `ping`s didn't work (couldn't route there?  i had no default GW set) but the `tcpdump` trick did it - I set my laptop to 192.168.0.0/16 and saw some traffic from an address that stood out, and that's where the router was (once I reset my address to something within the /24 range).  Thanks!

Comment: any solution for windows users ? this `ping 255.255.255.255` doesnt work on windows, also `arp -an` doesnt work, windows doesnt recognize the `-n` argunement, what is the windows equivalent ?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility that may work is if the FIOS tries to contact something when it boots then you should be able to see the packets being sent by the FIOS so
if you put a wire-shark capture on the laptop and plug it in then reboot the FIOS.   This may not happen - but hopefully its got NTP, or some call home/auto update check feature.
As mentioned in another answer some Unix distributions can do a broadcast ping (ie a ping to 255.255.255.255) so that may also help force a response however I tried this at home and of my roughly 30 devices on the network only 3 responded. Also I could not work out if the ARP table would of been filled in for devices not in the adapters sub-net.

I suggest to unbind everything from the adapter settings on the laptop to eliminate traffic being generated by the laptop.